# Objective C : NStimer- How to stop timer after n hours

Tags: objective-c, timer, nstimer

I have started the timer using below call, and need to stop it after n hours

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20 target:self selector:@selector(sendLocationUpdates) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The solution I can thin of get the current time when timer start and keep adding time till threshold reaches. Or is there any better way to stop timer?

Comment: Don't store your timer start time. Just schedule two timers. Your timer stored in `self.timer` and second one to fire after N hours. Invalidate your `self.timer` (first one) when your second timer fires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an instance variable to the class to store the start time of the timer:

YourClass.m:

```
@interface YourClass () {
    NSTimeInterval _startTime;
}

@end
```

Record the current time when creating the timer:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20 target:self selector:@selector(sendLocationUpdates) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
_startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

and test the current time in the `sendLocationUpdates` method:

```
#define TIMER_LIFE_IN_SECONDS 3000.0

- (void)sendLocationUpdates
{
    // do thing

    NSTimeInterval now = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    if (now - _startTime > TIMER_LIFE_IN_SECONDS) {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer, except that I think it would be better for `startTime` to be an `NSDate`; then write `if ( [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime] >= TIMER_LIFE_IN_SECONDS ){`

Comment: @JoshCaswell What difference would that make?

Comment: I think it makes the types clearer and thus the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution

declare two properties

```
@property NSInteger counter;
@property NSTimeInterval interval;
```

set the counter to 0 before starting the timer

```
  self.counter = 0;
  self.interval = 20.0;
  self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.interval target:self selector:@selector(sendLocationUpdates) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

in the `sendLocationUpdates` method increment the counter

```
  - (void)sendLocationUpdates
  {
    counter++;
    if (counter == 4 * (3600 / self.interval)) {
      [self.timer invalidate];
      self.timer = nil;
    }
   // do other stuff
  }
```

with a given time interval of 20 seconds the timer fires 180 times per hour.
In the example the timer stops after 4 hours

Comment: The time interval 20 is something which get as a response when I post the location, it is variable can be changed for each request.

Comment: of course you can do the math dynamically. I changed the post